# On a Windows phone, how can I block a phone number with the Windows 8 API?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I saw state and notification broker for Windows Mobile, but I can't find anything like it for Windows 8.

I found this for the older OS:

**http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32200/Own-your-phone-Taking-back-control-of-your-mobile**

Didn't see anything on MSDN.  Where can I start on this?

I don't care which language.  I have a Nokia if it matters.

EDIT:  Does this mean I can't build one?

https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-US/OEM/docs/Customization/Phone_call_SMS_filter_applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do this unless you are a OEM. Only OEMs have this functionality enabled for them. For normal developers such API does not exist for Windows Phone. Only partners with Microsoft can download the source code or view it.

Comment: Sad, but nothing I can do I guess.

Comment: you can add suggestions [here](http://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-dev-platform) ask for the API and get enough votes behind your request and may be we might get that feature. Add your idea and pls post your link here. So i can vote too :)

Answer (score 3):

These APIs are not exposed to third-party developers.